# I can't install FastX Toolkit on Linux

Tags: linux, makefile

I want to use FastX Toolkit on Linux Sever.
(link : http://hannonlab.cshl.edu/fastx_toolkit/download.html)

So I followed Fastx-toolkit installation on Ubuntu Method
(link : http://hannonlab.cshl.edu/fastx_toolkit/install_ubuntu.txt)

But In install libgtextutils part, raise error.

Especially, I did download libgtextutils file, decompress file, execute ./configure.

and I already installed gcc(version 7.5.0), pkg-config

But "make" and "make install" raise error
(fastX toolkit install error is also "make" and "make install" problem)

The errors that come out are as follows. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZH3J.png)

What should I do?

I'd appreciate it if you could answer.

PS. I can't use sudo or apt, because I'm a student and I'm not server administrator.

Comment: First, please don't post images, and most especially not links to images on other sites, to StackOverflow questions.  Questions here are meant to serve as a body of knowledge on how to fix issues and if your question contains links to other sites that might disappear that doesn't work, and attaching images means that the errors can't be searched for or copied into an answer.  Please cut and paste (with proper formatting!) the commands and errors into your question as text.

Comment: Second, that looks like a straight out bug in the code you're trying to compile.  That project was apparently last tested on with Ubuntu 9.10 which is 12 **years** old at this point.  It's quite possible that it will take some tweaking to make it work properly on current systems with newer compilers.

Comment: Maybe you should look on their GitHub site and see if a newer release has these problems fixed: https://github.com/agordon/fastx_toolkit

Comment: Also you might read carefully the disclaimer at the top of the README on the GitHub site...

Comment: fastx-toolkit 0.0.14 is used in Debian 10, and Fedora 21 .. 35. Example `fastx-toolkit_0.0.14.orig.tar.gz` ...... and  **gcc-7.patch**, etc. `fastx-toolkit_0.0.14-6.debian.tar.xz` https://packages.debian.org/buster/fastx-toolkit